# spatie Activity log is not capturing from queue and schedulars

Tags: laravel, spatie-activitylog

I am using laravel framework for developing API's and my application is a multi-tenancy database .
I am using spatie-Activity log package for capturing logs in model level it's working fine in either request came from web or api.

Based on Activity.php model(it's a package model) i am manipulating log messages and attributes by using observer it's also working fine for both either API or WEB.Now i am facing one scenario some fields are updating through queue-jobs (ORM only) but it's not capturing in the Activity table How can i make it happen to trigger in laravel . can anyone give me some suggestions to make it work.

Comment: Can you share some glimpse of your code, please?